# Get duration of a collection of audios

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am creating an audio player from an audio collection on an HTML page:

```
...
<div class="tr track" id="01">
  <div class="td">
    <button class="play" onclick="Play(this)">▶</button>
    <button class="play" onclick="Pause(this)">❚❚</button>
    <span class="title">A Corda da Liberdade</span>
  </div>
  <div class="td">
    <audio preload="metadata" src="discografia/le-gauche-gnosis/01-a-corda-da-liberdade.ogg"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="td">
    <span class="duracao"></span>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

I want the `<span class="duracao"></span>` element to show the duration of the audio it is related to:

```
// This function format the audio duration number in the way I want to present
function secToStr(sec_num) {
  sec_num = Math.floor( sec_num );
  var horas   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
  var minutos = Math.floor((sec_num - (horas * 3600)) / 60);
  var segundos = sec_num - (horas * 3600) - (minutos * 60);

  if (horas   < 10) {horas   = "0"+horas;}
  if (minutos < 10) {minutos = "0"+minutos;}
  if (segundos < 10) {segundos = "0"+segundos;}
  var tempo    = minutos+':'+segundos;
  return tempo;
}

var i;
var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio'); // get all audios elements of the player

for (i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) { // looping through audios

  var audio = audios[i]; // get actual audio
  var duracao = audio.parentNode.nextElementSibling.getElementsByClassName('duracao')[0] // get actual audio 'duration <span>'

  audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {

    duracao.innerHTML = secToStr(audio.duration);
  }
}
```

The `for` loop is supposed to do the job but is just adding the duration of the last audio element to the last `<span class="duracao"></span>` element:

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent place to learn about, and then use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of a for-loop.

The concept of `reduce` is that you start with some starting value (which can be anything, not just a number), and you then walk through the array in a way that, at ever step, lets you run some code to update that value. So:

```
const total = [1,2,3,4,5].reduce( (sofar, value) => sofar + value, 0)
```

will run through the array, with start value 0, and at every step it runs `(sofar, value) => sofar + value`, where the first argument is always "whatever the original start value is at this point". This function assumes that `value` is a number (or a string) and adds (or concatenates) it to the start value. So at each step we get:

```
start = 0
first element:  add 1 to this value: 0 + 1 = 1
second element: add 2 to this value: 1 + 2 = 3
third element:  add 3 to this value: 3 + 3 = 6
fourth element: add 4 to this value: 6 + 4 = 10
fifth element:  add 5 to this value: 10 + 5 = 15
```

We can apply the same to your audio elements: once they're all done loading in, you can tally their total duration with a single `reduce` call:

```
const total = audios.reduce((sofar, audioElement) => {
  sofar += audioElement.duration;
}, 0); // this "0" is the starting value for the reduce-function's first argument 

console.log(`Total number of seconds of play: ${total}`);
```

And then you can convert `total` into whatever format you need.

Alternatively, you can keep a global tally, but making each audo element update the total length themselves, simply by finishing loading:

```
let total = 0;

function updateTotal(increment) {
  total += increment;
  // and then update whatever HTML element shows that value on the page,
  // in whatever format you need.
}

document.querySelectorAll('audio').forEach(element => {
  element.onload = (evt) => {
    updateTotal(element.duration);        
  })
});
```

Comment: I tried to read the article but it seems a little too advanced for me. I couldn't understand how this method works in the context of my player. Can you please explain or provide me a solution that uses the for-loop? Thanks!

Comment: Also I'm using arrow functions a lot, because I write modern JS a lot; if you've not seen those before, you want to learn about them because they make JS a _lot_ nicer to work with (and preserve `this` based on where you declared the function, rather than where it executes, which in this code is not really important, but very often is _incredibly_ important)

Comment: With the `reduce` call the console is returning: `Uncaught TypeError: audios.reduce is not a function`. I'm using Chrome 75.0.3770.142 on Windows 10.

Comment: This will fail with more than 6 elements in Chrome and actually in most browsers (don't wait for `onload`...). `reduce` is absolutely not the good tool for async tasks.

Comment: The alternative with `onload` return `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAdd is not a function`

Comment: that was a typo, and should have been querySelectorAll

Comment: @Kaiido if you can explain _why_ more than 6 elements is a problem, that'd be greatly appreciated. The whole point of onload is that you're supposed to be able to rely on it, so if we can't, please let us know why that is (I'd certainly love to know for future reference). Not getting the info at the same time, as long as you have a global value to increment, shouldn't be an issue, you just get incremental updates over the entire load time.

Comment: [My answer gives the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57282677/3702797) for why more than 6 requests won't work. For onload, that's simply not part of the [MediaElement events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Events).

Answer (score 1):

The general approach with asynchronous loops would be to *promisify* the async action and then wait for a *`Promise.all(all_promises)`*.

However, in this particular case, it might not be that easy:

Some browsers ([Chrome to not tell their name](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162627#c1-)) have a limit on the maximum number of parallel network requests a page can make for Media.

From there, you won't be able to get the duration of more than six different media at the same time...

So we need to load them one after the other.

The *async/await* syntax introduced in ES6 can help here:

```js
const urls = [
  '1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3',
  'h8pvqqol3ovyle8/tom.mp3',
  'agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3',
  'should-break.mp3',
  '/hjx4xlxyx39uzv7/18660_1464810669.mp3',
  'kbgd2jm7ezk3u3x/hihat.mp3',
  'h2j6vm17r07jf03/snare.mp3'
]
 .map(url => 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/' + url);

getAllDurations(urls)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

async function getAllDurations(urls) {
  const loader = generateMediaLoader();
  let total = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    total += await loader.getDuration(urls[i]);
  }
  return total;
}

// use a single MediaElement to load our media
// this is a bit verbose but can be reused for other purposes where you need a preloaded MediaElement
function generateMediaLoader() {
  const elem = new Audio();
  let active = false; // so we wait for previous requests
  return {
    getDuration,
    load
  };
  // returns the duration of the media at url or 0
  function getDuration(url) {
    return load(url)
      .then((res) => res && res.duration || 0)
    .catch((_) => 0);
  }
  // return the MediaElement when the metadata has loaded
  function load(url) {
    if(active) {
      return active.then((_) => load(url));
    }
    return (active = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      elem.onloadedmetadata = e => {
        active = false;
        res(elem);
      };
      elem.onerror = e => {
        active = false;
        rej();
      };
      elem.src = url;
    }));
  }
}
```

But it's also very possible to make it ES5 style.

```js
var urls = [
  '1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3',
  'h8pvqqol3ovyle8/tom.mp3',
  'agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3',
  'should-break.mp3',
  '/hjx4xlxyx39uzv7/18660_1464810669.mp3',
  'kbgd2jm7ezk3u3x/hihat.mp3',
  'h2j6vm17r07jf03/snare.mp3'
]
 .map(function(url) {
  return 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/' + url;
 });

getAllDurations(urls, console.log);

function getAllDurations(urls, callback) {
  var loader = new Audio();
  var loaded = 0;
  var total = 0;
  
  loader.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    total += loader.duration;
    loadNext();
  };
  loader.onerror = loadNext;
  
  loadNext();

  function loadNext() {
    if(loaded >= urls.length) {
      return callback(total);
    }
    loader.src = urls[loaded++];
  }
}
```